# why this arrays changes its value itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, loops

In this html/javascript code I want to reassign Q to A every time k changes (in the first loop).
But I noticed that A change too!!
so how do I fix the problem ?

- why A changes its value although I am only changing Q ??
- how do I prevent A from changing ??
  thanks for answering

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var A=[[3,4],[5,7]];

var Q=[];

 for (var k=0;k<2;k++){
 
    Q= A;

    for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        Q[k][i]=1;
                    
       }
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  A;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because `Q = A` does **not** create a copy of the array, both `Q` and `A` references the same array object.

Comment: `Q= A` - you assigned a reference to `A` to `Q`, so when you changed `Q`, it changed `A`

Comment: When you assign A to Q, you set the reference to A so that both variables are assigned to the same array, but you need to clone the array like this `Q = [... A];`

Comment: @Cristian `Q = [...A];` wouldnt work

Comment: @LawrenceCherone right, my example is for single level array, for nested you can use `Q = JSON.parse (JSON.stringify (A))` or `cloneDeep` from lodash.

Comment: `var Q = A.map( item => new Array(item.length).fill(1));` would do the trick for what you are trying to do, but I guess this is just demo code, so you could do `var Q = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A))` to do a deep copy (provided there is no circular reference)

Comment: the json.parse/stringify trick would work but seems like a frowned upon bad practice or hack from partys which would suggest use lodashClonedeep etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone doesn't that depend on the context, if you know what the array will contain, I see no reason why you would need to import an entire library for it. Certainly not based on this demo code

Comment: Its fine to use imo, im not one of those people that jump on a lib.. a one-liner `const deepClone = v => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v))` is fine.. `Q = deepClone(A);` but this is SO after all. and there is many ways to clone it, from looping over to recursive map, or Array.from etc all shown in the dupe answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. Reference is made [here](https://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-clone-a-nested-array-in-javascript/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
     function arrayClone( arr ) {
     
         var i, copy;
     
         if( Array.isArray( arr ) ) {
             copy = arr.slice( 0 );
             for( i = 0; i < copy.length; i++ ) {
                 copy[ i ] = arrayClone( copy[ i ] );
             }
             return copy;
         } else if( typeof arr === 'object' ) {
             throw 'Cannot clone array containing an object!';
         } else {
             return arr;
         }
     
     }
     
     A=[[3,4],[5,7]];
     var Q=arrayClone(A);
     
      for (var k=0;k<2;k++){
         for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
             Q[k][i]=1;
                         
            }
       }
     
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  A;
     
  </script>
```

Comment: that's a bit of an overkill :) Especially for what the code does in the end

Comment: @DarrenChand thanks man